# All possible ways to trigger a button click in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webforms

I want to know all possible ways to trigger a button in jQuery, I tried this but it's not working,

```
$("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
```

**Note**: its a ASP.Net button and what I want is to trigger button click so that it will trigger a code-behind click method of buttonA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").click();
```

if it doesn't work try to alert this and check if it is getting accessed by JQ

```
alert($("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").length);
```

Have you registered the event with jquery in following manner

```
$(function(){
   $("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").click(function(){
   // your logic here
});
});
```

One more thing to confirm, are you loading this button directly on page load or you are having some page update panel which load it afterwords?

If yes then you should bind the event to button in following manner

```
$(document).on('click',"#<%=btA.ClientID%>", function() {...});
```

Comment: yup, length gives back alert box with "1"

Comment: you may need to trigger a DOM event.... in that case try this...
**("#<%=btA.ClientID%>")[0].click();** ... Hope this will work....

Comment: and if you still can't get it work, then you might have to try this...

**[Fire DOM Events](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2010/08/jquery-fireevent-plugin-for-firing-real.html)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").click();

Or

$("input[id$='yourbuttonId'").click();
```

Reason that trigger not working is Jquery only allow you to trigger a click that Jquery has created. Use the trigger route after you have written a click listener.

Answer (score 2):

Its beats me since it should be a very straightforward thing. I actually just tried it out and it worked without a hitch. Here is my markup:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbA" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btA" runat="server" OnClick="btA_Click" Text="Click Me!" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

... and I have this method in my code behind:

```
protected void btA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbA.Text = "Hello World!";
}
```

When the application runs, it triggers the `click` event of the `btA` button fires immediately and the **Hello World!** text is rendered on the label. Check if you could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").click();
```

I believe this is the only other way.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to wire the event,when the control itself is not loaded on to the page.

Try this instead.It buys a little bit of time and then wires up the event.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

Comment: sorry but my line of code is in "$(document).ready(function()", so I don't think thats the issue

Comment: right,but i had this similar issue ,when the trigger was not working even it was inside the document.ready(). setTimeout resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I always make ClientIdMode="static" so that you can easily call the element with the same id you configured in the page..

So you dont hvae to use ClientID.. More over you cant use asp.net code in a separate js file.

$("#<%=btA.ClientID%>").trigger('click');

to

$("#btA").click();